# uefi bootloaders for distributions

Tags: uefi

I have stared reading about uefi recently and got to know that SYSLINUX and GRUB2 have their own uefi bootloader. i have few confusions specially in terms of pxe boot.

1) Are distributions use their own uefi bootloader for n/w boot or is it like bios where every one is using pxelinux.0

2) Can we use uefi bootloader used for usbboot also for pxe boot.
3) Any link where all this details is explained?

I have read about so many boot loader like grubx64.efi, bootia.efi, grubia.efi, pxelinux64.efi.  Any information on this will be helpful.